# Julia: Abstract and Concrete Types Integer versus Int8 versus Int64

Tags: types, julia

Suppose I have an integer `n` that will only ever take values in `[0, 10]`. Should I declare it as `n::Integer` to be general about it, as `n::Int8` or `n::UInt8` to be parsimonious or `n::Int64` for a 64 bit system?

Please clarify the reasons for a newbie, e.g. style, performance.

Reference: https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/

**Updated Reference (2021):** https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-abstract-types

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's important to distinguish two different cases.

**Storage:** If you have a type that stores `n` as one of its fields, or as a value in an array, then you should definitely consider using `Int8` or `UInt8`. Even if the saved space for a single value is negligible, if many instances of your type are created and stored in a collection, then the space savings can rapidly become significant. Let's say you have a `Foo` type with a field `n`, then you might do this:

```
struct Foo
    n::UInt8
end
```

When a value is assigned to the `n` field of a `Foo` object, it will automatically be converted to `UInt8` and an error will be raised if the value cannot be converted faithfully:

```
julia> Foo(123) # Ints are automatically converted to UInt8
Foo(0x7b)

julia> typeof(ans.n)
UInt8

julia> Foo(500) # if too large, an error is raised
ERROR: InexactError()
Stacktrace:
 [1] Foo(::Int64) at ./REPL[1]:2

julia> Foo(-1) # ditto if too small
ERROR: InexactError()
Stacktrace:
 [1] Foo(::Int64) at ./REPL[1]:2

julia> Foo(2π/π)
Foo(0x02)
```

If the value that's assigned is already of the correct type then no check is required so there's no overhead.

**Dispatch:** If you are writing a method of a function that takes `n` as an argument, then there's no harm in having as loose a type annotation on the `n` argument as makes sense semantically. In the case you've described, it seems that any kind of integer value would be sensible, so using `n::Integer` would probably be appropriate. For example, if wanted to implement a checked constructor for `Foo` objects, you could do this:

```
struct Foo
    n::UInt8

    function Foo(n::Integer)
        0 <= n <= 10 || throw(ArgumentError("n not in [0, 10]: $n"))
        return new(n)
    end
end
```

Now an error is thrown if a value outside of [0, 10] is given:

```
julia> Foo(123)
ERROR: ArgumentError: n not in [0, 10]: 123
Stacktrace:
 [1] Foo(::Int64) at ./REPL[26]:2

julia> Foo(3)
Foo(0x03)
```

This `Foo` construction works for any kind of integer, checking that it's in the correct range, and then converting to `UInt8`. This is slightly more restrictive than the built-in constructor for `Foo`, which will happily take *any* kind of `n` argument and try to convert it to `UInt8` – even when the argument is not of an integer type. If that kind of behavior is desirable, you could loosen the type signature here further to `n::Real`, `n::Number` (or even `n::Any`, although that seems excessive).

Note that there is no performance advantage to tightly typed method arguments – the specialized code for actual argument types is generated on demand anyway.

Comment: Thanks for phrasing this much more clearly than I had managed to do! In the specific case, though, - do you have any comment on my impression that lots of functions in packages dispatch on Int rather than on Integer as they should - and that this may cause problems when using `UInt`s ?

Comment: I think that may be an issue, but in such cases the dispatch signature should probably be loosened, so opening an issue on the package to request that would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: As a concrete example, when we made `linspace` return a `LinSpace` object there was a rash of complaints from people being forced to call `collect` on the result in order to pass it into various function. This was actually just a symptom that these function should accept a broader range of inputs – since one doesn't generally need an actual in-memory vector and `LinSpace` acts just like a vector otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: refer to Stefan's accepted answer. I meant this is a response to the use of types in function dispatch, but in fact contradicted myself (as I do say explicitly that function dispatch should actually be Integer).

I'd always use `Int`, just for the generality of it, but it depends how performance-critical your application is. Never `Int64` unless you explicitly need it. Many functions dispatch on `Int` rather than `Integer`(though the advice is to dispatch on abstract types), which means that they will fail when passed a UInt8 (because `Int` is a subtype of `Signed` and `UInt` isn't) so being overzealous with types will cause problems.
As a general rule-of-thumb you should never be more specific with types than you have to.

Comment: Thanks Michael! So no performance gains for being more specific?

Comment: Perhaps you could comment on why the opposite appears to be often said of ``Float``, i.e. be specific rather than general?

Comment: No I think there is a performance gain but mostly I would think it was more trouble than advantage. But RGB s in Colors, for instance, are implemented using N0f8, which is a FixedPointNumber floating-point value based on UInt8. This makes sense because with images you really need to be able to compress them, and you've got good control of the types inside the RGB type.

Comment: Couldn't say about Floats - let's wait till some of the guys really in the know comment here :-)

Comment: @PatrickT doc: (Note that unlike Int, Float does not exist as a type alias for a specific sized AbstractFloat. Unlike with integer registers, the floating point register sizes are specified by the IEEE-754 standard. Whereas the size of Int reflects the size of a native pointer on that machine.)

Comment: @PatrickT also see pao's answer in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/julia-users/float$20type$20alias/julia-users/1tDvMbfCUEE/BJCu0-S7OawJ).

Comment: `Int` is specific: it just means `Int32` or `Int64` depending on the OS. But every OS uses `Float64`.

Comment: There's no performance gains for being specific on the type that you dispatch on, ever.

Comment: No but there might be a performance gain on using a smaller type, right?

Comment: Yes, @ChrisRackauckas Int is specific but depends on the system, that's why I'd never use Int64 unless I really needed it. I don't think we disagree but I may not have been clear. What I meant by "generality" is just that it's a much more commonly used type, and many functions dispatch on Int so that's why I'd prefer that to some specific small Int. Do you disagree with that?

Comment: Yes, any function which is writing a dispatch should at least do `Int`. `Integer` is better though, since there's no cost to doing expanding function definitions due to auto-specialization, and then the user can optimize usage themselves by using a smaller integer type if they like. I believe we agree here. Note that a very good example of this is LightGraphs.jl.

Comment: Agreed! -20 chars

Comment: Using a smaller type, or an unsigned type, might give better performance, so, for function arguments, I'd declare them just as `Integer`, not `Int`, because that might be too restrictive.  For example, if you have generic code, that has a test `if foo > 1000 ; ... ; end`, and `foo` was declared as `Int`, then it will always have that check, however, if it is declared as `Integer`, then if you pass in a `Int8`, Julia can tell that that test is always false, and get rid of the if block.  (This was the most surprising thing for me, when learning Julia).

Comment: For fields in a struct (type), I'd use the smallest concrete type that works, and lay them out so that the storage is as small as possible [for example, instead of `Int8, Int, Int8, Int32, Int16`, which would take 8+8+4+4+4 (+4) = 32 bytes, I'd have `Int, Int32, Int16, Int8, Int8`, which takes only 16 bytes], when the struct is used in arrays. Also, you can parameterize the types, if you don't know in advance just what types are needed. I also use `UInt*` when I know the values cannot be negative, which gives more information to the compiler for later optimization.

Comment: Thanks Chris, thanks Scott for chiming in. Very useful tips. Now, I gather from your comments that there is an ``Integer`` type that I did not mention in my OP, and that it's the most general and abstract. Well going back to the docs listed in my OP, I can't find a description of this. There's a section called __Integers__ but I don't think it refers to that. So unless I misunderstood things, it seems to me that the docs could be expanded and clarify the points discussed here. These points perhaps also deserve an answer for my upvotes. Thanks!

Comment: `Integer` is an abstract type, which has 2 concrete subtypes in Base, `Bool` and `BigInt`, as well as 2 abstract subtypes, `Signed` and `Unsigned` (which respectively have `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, and `Int128`, and `UInt8`, `UInt16`... for concrete subtypes).  `Int` is not a type, it is a typealias, which is aliased to `Int64` on 64-bit platforms, and `Int32` on 32-bit platforms. If you just do `?Integer` at the Julia REPL, it will give you the documentation that `Integer <: Real`, and "Abstract supertype for all integers"

Comment: So to summarise - what type to use depends on the context. Rule-of-thumb: wide abstract types in function calls, and mainly when you need it for dispatch (it's fine not to type). The specific type inside struct definitions. But add to that one complication, that many functions disregard this and dispatch on Int, which means that using a different Int or a UInt will cause code to fail that shouldn't...

Comment: @ScottJones I get it, ``Integer`` is an ``abstract type``, while ``Int`` is a ``typealias``. This helps a great deal in clarifying. @MichaelK.Borregaard, I accepted Stefan's answer as it is remarkably detailed, but again I'm very grateful for your advice and suggestions! :-)

Comment: Can't argue with that :-)

Comment: I take comfort in the fact that he's essentially saying the same thing, just better

Answer (score 2):

For a newcomer (like myself) reading the [abstract type docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-abstract-types-1) cleared things up. In addition, checking the following helped (`<:` reads 'is a subtype of'):

```
julia> Int<:Integer
true

julia> UInt<:Integer
true
```

and

```
julia> Int64<:Int
true
```

Comment: The last example would return false in a 32bit PC because, in this case, Int = Int 32.